# About to migrate :string but I'm thinking :text might be better. Performance/Purpose?

Tags: sql, ruby, string, text, migrate

```
class CreateScrapes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :scrapes do |t|
      t.text :saved_characters
      t.text :sanitized_characters
      t.string :href

      t.timestamps
   end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :scrapes
  end
end
```

I'm about to rake db:migrate and I'm think about the attribute type if I should be using `text` or `string`. Since `saved_characters` and `sanitized_characters` will be arrays with thousands of unicode values, its basically comma delimited data, I'm not sure if `:text' is really the right way to go here. What would you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're on MySQL, the real difference between `:string` and `:text` is length. Rails uses the `varchar` column type for `:string` columns, and sets a 255 character limit on `:string` columns. `:text`, usuprisingly, uses the `text` column.

To me, this suggests that `:string` would be a really bad choice for your columns, as they are likely to exceed 255 characters.

Answer (score 2):

:string is only 255 characters. you probably want :text since you mention thousands.